# Will catching an exception catch a parent class of that exception

Tags: java, exception

In Java I have a method catching an exception 'ChildException' that extends 'NewException'. If that method calls another method that throws a 'NewException' and let's say something happens and throws it; will the caller method that catches a child class of the exception thrown catch it?

```
public MethodCatchingChildException
{
  try
  {
     //stuff
     callingMethodThrowingNewException();
     //stuff
  }
  catch (ChildException e)
  {
     //stuff
  }
}
```

So will the exception from callingMethodThrowingNewException get caught in MethodCatchingChildException?

Comment: You have it backwards.  Catching the parent will catch the child, but not the other way around.

Comment: I am sorry but you could just write the code and see the results

Comment: well, actually i can't where i am. That's why I asked here. I am looking into some code that is not mine and can't compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `catch` clause will catch any exception that is assignment-compatible with the declared type of the exception. In the case you describe, an instance of `NewException` (that is not a `ChildException`) will not be caught by that `catch` clause because you cannot assign a `NewException` object to a `ChildException` variable.

The rules are spelled out in [section 14.20.1 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.1):

> If execution of the try block completes abruptly because of a throw of a value V, then there is a choice:
>
> - If the run-time type of V is assignment compatible with ([§5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)) a catchable exception class of any catch clause of the try statement, then the first (leftmost) such catch clause is selected. The value V is assigned to the parameter of the selected catch clause, and the Block of that catch clause is executed, and then there is a choice:
>
>   - If that block completes normally, then the try statement completes normally.
>   - If that block completes abruptly for any reason, then the try statement completes abruptly for the same reason.
> - If the run-time type of V is not assignment compatible with a catchable exception class of any catch clause of the try statement, then the try statement completes abruptly because of a throw of the value V.

Answer (score 1):

It will only catch the Exception you specify or it's subclass. Just write it so it catches the parent Exception and you're safe.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as an *instanceof* test

e.g.

```
if (e instanceof ChildException) {
 ...
}
```

so specifying a class type will catch the class *and* its subclasses.